# Difference between app.config and appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, app-config

I am trying to create a console application using .NET framework 4.7.2. I see an `app.config` file by default present in the project.

`App.config` is used to store configuration details of project. Just wanted to know the difference between `app.config` and `appsettings.json`

Comment: Since there is already two answers, I'll add this as a comment. `app.config` was part of a layering concept, where there was also a `user` and and a `machine` config. But since deployments are getting more and more atomic (containerization), there is no need for such things in many cases and a much more lightweight format like `appsettings.json` can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

app.config is used to store configuration details for a .NET Framework application, and it's a traditional way to store configuration data in XML format. However, in recent times, there's a trend towards using appsettings.json files instead of app.config for storing configuration data in .NET applications.

The main difference between app.config and appsettings.json is the format of the data they store. app.config uses XML format, while appsettings.json uses JSON format.

Another difference is that app.config is specific to .NET Framework, while appsettings.json is used in .NET Core applications. You also get web.config, which is used specifically for a .NET Framework Web based application.

In your case I would go with what the framework provided and use the app.config file.

Comment: You will find that System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager is still bundled with .NET Core, so you can still use app.config without having to add any new packages or dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some key differences

- app.config is used usually in .NET Framework applications, while appsettings.json is commonly used in .NET Core applications.
- app.config uses XML format to store the configuration, appsettings.json uses JSON format. JSON is easier to read and write compared to XML.
- appsettings.json makes it easier to manage specific configurations for specific environments (you can have different JSON files for each environment appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Production.json).

Comment: “JSON is easier” is rather subjective. XML syntax is more verbose, but I don’t think it any harder.

Answer (score 2):

"app.config" is typically used in older .NET Framework applications - format with XML, while "appsettings.json" is used in .NET Core applications - With json format

Answer (score 0):

From a programmer's perspective, the difference also is that the `app.config` XML is not edited by hand but configured using a class called `Settings` code which is configured via UI in Visual Studio by opening the `Settings.settings` file.
The key-value pairs are immediately added as properties to the `Settings` class and immediately serialized to XML so everything is compile-time checked in real time. A bit similar to how Windows Forms designer works.
The keys and values can then be accessed in code via public properties of the Settings class.

While `appsettings.json` in ASP.NET Core is plain text (JSON) file without any built-in validation when edited.
This makes it much more prone to mistakes (typos) and also divergence in the config file vs code (no class with no public properties, but `.GetSection(string)` compared to `app.config` in .NET Framework.